# How can I use the go language to specify the namespace of wmi when calling wmi?

Tags: go, wmi

I was asked to use the Go language to obtain some computer configurations of the local computer, such as CPU model and memory size,but there was a problem when getting some configurations.

When I get the basic CPU information, I use the following code, which works well because `Win32_ Processor` from `root\cimv2`

```
type cpuInfo struct {
    Name          string
    NumberOfCores uint32
    ThreadCount   uint32
    Architecture  uint32
}

func getCPUInfo() {

    var cpuinfo []cpuInfo

    err := wmi.Query("Select * from Win32_Processor", &cpuinfo)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("Cpu info =", cpuinfo)
    fmt.Println()
}
```

But when I need to obtain some special information, such as whether the network card is a physical network card, whether the hard disk is SSD or HDD, I need to use `MSFT_ NetAdapter` and `MSFT_ PhysicalDisk`, whose namespaces are not `root\cimv2`,They come from `root\StandardCimv2` and `\root\microsoft\windows\storage`.
When I use the following code to obtain this information, the returned value is null

```
type networkInfo struct {
    Name              string
    DriverDescription string
    InterfaceName     string
}

func getNetworkInfo() {

    var networkinfo []networkInfo
    query := wmi.CreateQuery(&networkinfo, "Select * from MSFT_NetAdapter where Virtual=false")
    err := wmi.QueryNamespace(query, &networkinfo, "Root\\StandardCimv2")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("Network Info=", networkinfo)
    fmt.Println()
}
```

When I use C# to call this class, I get the information I need correctly

```
var objectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\StandardCimv2", $@"select DriverDescription, Name, InterfaceName, InterfaceType, NdisPhysicalMedium from MSFT_NetAdapter where ConnectorPresent=1"); //Physical adapter

foreach (var managementObject in objectSearcher.Get())
{
    var interfaceName = managementObject["InterfaceName"]?.ToString();
    var interfaceType = Convert.ToUInt32(managementObject["InterfaceType"]);
    var ndisPhysicalMedium = Convert.ToUInt32(managementObject["NdisPhysicalMedium"]);
    var driverDescription = managementObject["DriverDescription"]?.ToString();
    var name = managementObject["Name"]?.ToString();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(interfaceName) &&
        interfaceType == 6 &&       
        (ndisPhysicalMedium == 0 || ndisPhysicalMedium == 14))   //802.3
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name:" + name);
        Console.WriteLine("DriverDescription:" + driverDescription);
        Console.WriteLine("InterfaceName:" + interfaceName);
    }
}
```

How should I use the Go language to specify the namespace to call the class I need?

Comment: is it because a typo on `Root\\StandardCimv2` where you used capital `R`, you said it's on `root\StandardCimv2`.

Comment: @dakdikduk I used ```root\StandardCimv2``` and ```root\standardCimv2```,but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure your machine has this namespace?  It doesn't exist on my win10 VM.  Try launching WMI Explorer, check that this namespace exists.

Comment: @AlexandrKamenev When I use C# to call this class, I get the information I need correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the function wmi.CreateQuery() incorrectly. See the parameters description on https://github.com/StackExchange/wmi/blob/v1.2.1/wmi.go#L566.
You must replace your query in getNetworkInfo():

```
query := wmi.CreateQuery(&networkinfo, "Virtual=false", "MSFT_NetAdapter")
err := wmi.QueryNamespace(query, &networkinfo, "Root\\StandardCimv2")
```

And it makes absolutely no difference whether to write Root or root in wmi.QueryNamespace(). I checked.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!@AlexandrKamenev
It takes effect after I modify the second parameter of CreateQuery() to "WHERE Virtual=false"

Answer (score 0):

Thank @AlexandrKamenev!I'm sure I got the answer I wanted.Use the QueryNamespace() method to specify namespace:

Directly use QueryNamespace() method:

```
err := wmi.QueryNamespace("Select * from MSFT_PhysicalDisk", &diskMediaTypeInfo, "root\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Storage")
```

Use CreateQuery() with QueryNamespace() method

```
query := wmi.CreateQuery(&networkinfo, "WHERE Virtual=false", "MSFT_NetAdapter")
err := wmi.QueryNamespace(query, &networkinfo, "root\\StandardCimv2")
```

it works!